# Creating an RViz Plugin with animations

Tags: ros, rviz, ogre, rviz-plugins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

First of all, Ubuntu 64 bit 12.04 Hydro.

I'm trying to make an RViz plugin with animations.  To get started, I modified the code from the tutorial:

http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/rviz_plugin_tutorials/html/display_plugin_tutorial.html

If I try to do some sort of "animation" though, by creating a marker, sleeping, updating the marker, sleeping, etc., this doesn't cause anything to render.  I'm guessing that this is because I'm making the entire RViz system sleep, so it can't update.

In order to get around this, for each incoming message, I fire off a thread tahtthen is in charge of painting for this thread.  Unfortunately, this has led to numerous graphical glitches - and after the first one, it fails to paint for subsequent loops.

So much is abstracted away from the user in these plugins (it's actually extremely frustrating!) that I really do not have a good grasp on how the painting occurs.  And there is little to no documentation on these things.

I'm looking for an explanation as to how the painting actually occurs, and possibly a suggestion on how to do animations correctly?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/149796/creating-an-rviz-plugin-with-animations/) by [aespielberg](https://answers.ros.org/users/147/aespielberg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2014-04-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Audi](https://answers.ros.org/users/22946/audi/) on 2016-06-17**:
Hi, this question is old, but can I check what is the solution to this? I want to create animation in RViz plugin as well, and bumped into similar problem if I used the update-sleep-update-sleep-... approach. RViz would only show the last published markers. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you can inherit directly from the `rviz::Display` class, and override the `void update(float wall_dt, float ros_dt)` method to do your own drawing every time rviz does a drawing cycle. You should be able to use that to do your own animation.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0